# Replacing each letter with another letter

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am wondering how to replace each letter of a string with another letter. For example `A -> D`.

I have tried using `.replace()` (repeating it in each line for every letter) but when I replace the letter A with the letter D and then try to replace the letter D with the letter H it just replaces the letter A twice so instead of `AD -> DH` I end up with `AD -> HH`.

I'm sure there is a better and simpler way of doing this.

Answer (score 3):

Build up a dictionary:

```
 const dict = { A: "D", D: "A", /*...*/ };
```

Then split the string into an array, map that to a new array by applying the replacement and join the array back to a string:

```
 const output = input.split("").map(char => dict[char]).join("");
```

Comment: You may also use the `replace` method directly like so: `input.replace(/./g, c => dict[c] || c)`.